# get all Queue from activeMQ

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am new to *activeMQ*. I need to write code to get all the Queues and read the messages.
I did not find any API like get all Queues.
How can I read the Queues from *ActiveMQ*.If possible some example will be helpful.

Comment: What are you using? Native API? JMS binding? JEE MDB?

Answer (score 5):

Get all Queues in ActiveMQ in java.

Add Below Maven dependencies in **pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>  

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-spring</artifactId>
    <version>5.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You can change **tcp://localhost:61616/** to **tcp://180.50.50.10:61616/** where activemq service is running.

**Java Code:**

```
try {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616/");

    ActiveMQConnection connection = (ActiveMQConnection) connectionFactory.createConnection();
    DestinationSource ds = connection.getDestinationSource();

    connection.start();

    Set<ActiveMQQueue> queues = ds.getQueues();

    for (ActiveMQQueue activeMQQueue : queues) {
        try {
            System.out.println(activeMQQueue.getQueueName());
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    connection.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Console Output:**

```
HtmlQueue
emaildewsgmc
pdfdirectinpirepscli
pdfdirectinpirecli
InQueue
ReceiveQueue
NormalPriorityQueue
emaildirecthp
pdfdewsgmc
pdfdirecthp
Send2Recv
SaveQueue
LowPriorityQueue
emaildewshp
HighPriorityQueue
PdfQueue
AnotherDest
pdfdewshp
emaildirectgmc
```

Answer (score 1):

Man You are already using a API named activeMQ and from this API You can get all the queues.
I am unable to understand your this part of question where you said 
* I did not find any api like get Q*

Anyway you can use the **[JMX](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html)** for this.
The easiest way is to use JMX by pointing your JMX console or JConsole at the broker JVM.

**programmatically** You can also get all of the active destinations from the broker using Java code via [getDestinations()](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.5.0/activemq-core/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/broker/Broker.html#getDestinations%28%29).
You can also get a Map of all the Destination objects indexed by ActiveMQDestination via getDestinationMap(). This allows you to look at the individual destination details such as the queue depths and so forth
The last way is to use the **[WebConsole](http://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html).** The ActiveMQ Web Console is a web based administration tool for working with ActiveMQ. When used with the JMX support it can be an invaluable tool for working with ActiveMQ.
Please follow the [detailed support of ActiveMQ on their website where you can find almost everything](http://activemq.apache.org/index.html) :)

Comment: I tried getDestinations and getDestinationMap but getDestinations  return me blank array and The getDestinationMap not find. Can you please give me some code base. Like what should be the url(imean http://localgost:8082 or tcp://localhost:616161) Please let me know. Thank you

Comment: Perhaps there are no queues defined on the broker, try calling createQueue() then call getDestinations()